# How can I convert this into a string?

Tags: jquery

I google search for a long time on this topic but the sites I visit are always not what i'm looking for or are either ambiguous so according to the main jquery site

the data can be a String or a PlainObject

[Screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCEuf.png)

I know how to do the object version but how can I convert the var data object into a string version.

Here's my code

**index**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = "x";
var data = {
name: "John Doe ",
city: "Las Vegas"
}
var success = function(response){$("#callback_id").html(response);
}
$("#execute").click(function(){
 $.post(url,data,success);
$("#execute").hide();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery.post with url,data,success & dataType</h1>
<div id="callback_id"></div>
<button id="execute">Click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$city = $_POST["city"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#data_output {
border: 5px dotted red;
width: 180px;
}
#go_back{
  padding: 5px; 5px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img width="250" src="http://i57.servimg.com/u/f57/17/89/85/30/u-qudi10.jpg">
<p id="data_output"><?php echo "Name: $name"; ?></p>
<p id="data_output"><?php echo "From: $city"; ?></p>
<a id="go_back" href/codex/library/ajax/jquery/post/code_example/other/x/" >Go Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[Screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BMQM.gif)

Comment: `JSON.stringify(data)`?

Comment: No idea what you're asking `JSON.stringify({name: "John Doe",city: "Las Vegas"})` returns a string representation of your object. No additional ugly characters involved. Unless you mean the backslashes used to escape the double quotes?

Comment: what do you mean "ugly characters" ? BTW I don't understand why you need to send string if you have object. $.post doesn't matter what you use.

Comment: Yes it does I only want John Doe and Las Vegas not the quotes and commas characters  and : :  I want the same output as the gif but a string version of  the output look at the second screen shoot I mentioned It's a gif, jquery.com mentions you can do a string so how can you do a string as an ouput rather than a PlainObject https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: The second screen shoot is where it say's output look at that to see what I mean.

Comment: If you send object as string "JSON.stringify(data)" with $.post .. you can use json_decode($_POST) in php to get array of values again http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `$.param(data)`?

Comment: I don't want to do an object or convert the object I want to do a string instead for example var data = "John Doe " + "Las Vegas"; but that does not work so I want to learn how I can do a string not an object any more with $post(). Because https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ said you can do a plainObject or a string so I want to know how to do a string of John Doe and Las Vegas and output it in page x.php with the help of $post() and I know what a string is but jquery shouldn't be mentioning a string and not give a detail example of it just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `String` version of `data` in an $.ajax or $.post call is to put the variables in a concatenated url style. For your case...

```
var data = 'name=John+Doe&city=Las+Vegas';
```

... that you can also create using `$.param`...

```
var data = $.param(data);
```

Is that what you where looking for?

Comment: Thank you every one who got involve in this topic I'm sorry if I confuse some of you unintentionally but thanks for your attempts to try to help me out on this and thank you A. Iglesias that's the answer I wanted. var data = 'name=John+Doe&city=Las+Vegas';

Comment: Good to hear! Have a nice day and happy coding!!